# Index error while creating a new dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy

Got this error while creating a new dataframe. Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'type': 20, 'status': 'good', 'info': 'text'},
                        index=[0])

Out[0]: TypeError: Cannot interpret '<attribute 'dtype' of 'numpy.generic' objects>' as a data type
```

I tried also pass index with quotation marks but it didn't work either.

Numpy version:

```
np.__version__
Out[1]: '1.20.1'
```

Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just checked your code in my environment and it works ok.

I assume your Pandas lib might be outdated.

Here is the related github issue:
https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/18355

Thanks!

Comment: Downgrading numpy solved this problem. Via pip install --upgrade numpy==1.18.1. Do not use numpy 1.20.1 atm.